# How to get data using Axios and store it in Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I've a individual file to get the data from Api and

```
const FetchLanguageList = () => {
  const [isLanguage, setIsLanguage] = useState(true);

  API.get(`en/restaurants/1/languages`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn(err);
    });
};

export default FetchLanguageList;
```

How Do I store the `console.log(res.data)` to my redux store?
For now I've nothing inside my store, and have default template counter slice.
I want to get the API data and store it in redux store, then dispatch the data to my UI componenet.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do the API call inside of this function and make dispatch to your redux store with the data received or you could use something like redux-thunk or redux-sagas to fetch the data inside of your dispatch (which I would recommend as it would simplify the logic inside of your component)

Comment: I can't call api inside the function. Could you share me some docs/videos on redux-thunk?

Comment: [Redux-thunk docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and a [Article on how to use it](https://medium.com/how-to-react/how-to-use-redux-in-your-react-app-with-axios-2327f581bf8a)